# Laravel:How to use eloquent to query database with a certain date in (dd/mm/yyy)

Tags: php, database, laravel, date, eloquent

Hello I'm using laravel and I want users to be able to filter based on a created at date in the format (dd/mm/yyy)  e.g  23/08/2016

The database save the created_at field as a timestamp like so `2016-08-25 13:28:04`.

Is there a way to convert so that the following query is possible:

```
Model::whereDate('created_at', '=', $filter['created_at']);
```

Thanks you.

Comment: What's the question? Converting the date into the correct format?

Comment: why is that query not possible?

Comment: @simon Yes I am asking how to convert so that users can enter the date in the dd/mm/yyy format and then I can use that date to query the create_at timestamp in the database.

Comment: Either use @jaysingkar answer or take a look at [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used HTML data input it worked without having to convert anything.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is efficient, but you can use `Carbon` and `whereDate()` methods to achieve this.

```
Model::whereDate('created_at','=',Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/yyyy',$filter['created_at']));
```